# Use Android JobScheduler to test for network connectivity

Tags: android, android-networking, android-jobscheduler

For Android Nougat 7.0 and above, it is recommended to use JobScheduler instead of a broadcast receiver to test for network connectivity.  I've seen many posts and articles that state this and point to official docs.  But I can't seem to find a specific example of using JobScheduler for this specific purpose.

Does someone have an example of using JobScheduler to specifically check that a network connection is available? Or can you point me to an example?

Comment: Testing for a network connection typically is useless on its own. Usually, you are testing for a network connection in order to be able to do something specific (e.g., sync data with a server). That's the sort of scenario that `JobScheduler` is for, via [`setRequiredNetworkType()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder.html#setRequiredNetworkType(int)).

Comment: @CommonsWare  My app only works properly is the device is connected to a network.  So instead of sending my users to a sign in process, for one example i would rather show them a screen that says they are off line.  This is simple to do with a broadcast receiver, but that is no longer recommended.  If JobScheduler is Not useful for this, what is recommended?

Comment: "This is simple to do with a broadcast receiver" -- not really. Moreover, neither a `BroadcastReceiver` nor `JobScheduler` are relevant here. Those are for background operations; your scenario is a foreground one. "what is recommended?" -- first, make an actual request of your server. If that succeeds, you not only have connectivity, but you can reach the server, and all is well. If it fails, use `ConnectivityManager` and `getActiveNetworkInfo()` to see if there is a network connection (but perhaps one you cannot use due to a firewall, proxy, etc.).

Comment: @CommonsWare  Ok I will look into what you're saying, I guess I'm approaching it incorrectly.  But its sure seemed simple to me to use a broadcast receiver with ConnectivityManager and getActiveNetworkInfo so I could know network availability beforehand, instead of testing for it after the call to backend fails.  thanks for your responses.